# Entity Framework adding / deleting a new object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I add a new object to an EntityCollection:

```
myThingHolder.Things.Add(myThing);
```

... then later, using the same ObjectContext, before ever saving to the database, I do:

```
myObjectContext.Things.DeleteObject(myThing);
```

I get an exception: "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."

Other than doing

```
myThingHolder.Things.Remove(myThing);
```

is there another solution? I'd like to be able to independently delete the object--just like I can do if the object has been saved previously.

**EDIT**

I should note that this problem only occurs when myThingHolder is also new and has not yet been saved to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to attach the object to your context. Take a look at [attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) on MSDN for more information.